# run tensorflow textsum model on gpu

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

On cpu, the textsum training code (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/textsum) runs flawlessly.

To run code on gpu for faster training, I have changed "cpu" to "gpu" in following 4 lines:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/textsum/seq2seq_attention.py#L84
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/textsum/seq2seq_attention_model.py#L149
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/textsum/seq2seq_attention_model.py#L217
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/textsum/seq2seq_attention_model.py#L228

Model is still getting trained, but again on cpu, and not on gpu. (I checked it by using nvidia-smi)

Please let me know if anything else needs to be changed to train it on gpu.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this lines of code will help you in training model on GPU

***textsum/seq2seq_attention.py***

```
# change this line
# tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_gpus', 0, 'Number of gpus used.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_gpus', 1, 'Number of gpus used.')
```

***textsum/seq2seq_attention_model.py***

```
# if self._num_gpus > 1:
#     self._cur_gpu = (self._cur_gpu + 1) % (self._num_gpus-1)
self._cur_gpu = (self._cur_gpu + 1) % (self._num_gpus-1 if self._num_gpus > 1 else self._num_gpus)
```

reference issue [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/356)